# trying to install wfuzz giving me errors

Tags: pip

I'm trying to use wfuzz
but i get this error : userWarning:fuzz needs pycurl to run. Pycurl could be installed using the following command:

```
$ pip install pycurl
```

when I type pip install pycurl
I get this error

```
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typing_extensions-4.8.0.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/certifi-2023.7.22.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyYAML-6.0.1.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/six-1.16.0-py3.11.egg-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lxml-4.9.3.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typing_extensions-4.8.0.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/certifi-2023.7.22.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyYAML-6.0.1.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/six-1.16.0-py3.11.egg-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lxml-4.9.3.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/Pygments-2.16.1.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click-8.1.7.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/packaging-23.2.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cffi-1.16.0.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
Requirement already satisfied: pycurl in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (7.45.2)
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typing_extensions-4.8.0.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/certifi-2023.7.22.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyYAML-6.0.1.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/six-1.16.0-py3.11.egg-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lxml-4.9.3.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/Pygments-2.16.1.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click-8.1.7.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/packaging-23.2.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cffi-1.16.0.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
DEPRECATION: wfuzz 3.1.0 has a non-standard dependency specifier pyparsing>=2.4*; python_version >= "3.5". pip 24.0 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to upgrade to a newer version of wfuzz or contact the author to suggest that they release a version with a conforming dependency specifiers. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12063
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typing_extensions-4.8.0.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/certifi-2023.7.22.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyYAML-6.0.1.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/six-1.16.0-py3.11.egg-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lxml-4.9.3.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typing_extensions-4.8.0.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typing_extensions-4.8.0.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
```

I'm using mac OS big sur 11 could that be the problem ?